# If a matrix A square is 0, does it follow that A = 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let A be a square matrix. If $A^2 = 0$, then it follows that $A = 0$.

Is there a counterexample for this? If there isn't, what kinds of explanation can I make to justify this statement?

Comment: No. Consider $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another example:
\begin{align}
\left[ \begin{matrix}
2 & 1 \\ -4 & -2
\end{matrix}\right]
\end{align}
or more general
\begin{align}
\left[ \begin{matrix}
ab & a^2 \\ -b^2 & -ab
\end{matrix}\right]
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

$$A = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$$
is a classic example.

---

More theoretically: if $A^2 = 0$, then $\det A = 0$. Hence $A$ in Jordan Canonical Form (JCF) is either $$J_1 = \left( \begin{matrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & -\lambda \end{matrix} \right) \ \text{ or } \ J_2 = \left( \begin{matrix} \lambda & 1 \\ 0 & -\lambda \end{matrix} \right)$$

As $J_1^2 = 0$ implies $\lambda = 0$ it follows $J_1 = 0$ and hence the JCF must be of the form $J_2$. Now, $$J_2^2 = \left( \begin{matrix} \lambda^2 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda^2 \end{matrix} \right)$$ and hence $\lambda = 0$.

Therefore *any* $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ such that $A \neq 0$ and $A^2 = 0$ must have Jordan Canonical Form $J_2 = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$. This can be confirmed directly for the other examples given in other responses.

Answer (score 4):

This is not true. Consider $\eta = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1  \\
  -1 & -1  \\
 \end{pmatrix}$.